# Is it possible to get the post from wordpress into html files and then import them again

Tags: wordpress, plugins, import, themes, export

Hi guys I am new to wordpress and I am with a new group of web developers who are trying to import the content from a old website to a new one with a new theme, the problem with the old website is that we are having some anomalies with the old theme and plugins and all these kind of stuff I know that we can just import all the content to the new theme to a clean wordpress installation but we are not sure if the anomalies and bugs from the old website will be imported in any kind of way as well, so what we are doing is copying and past every singles post from the old website but it is crazy to that I was wondering if could it be possible to get the posts like in html format and then import then again so it is the same thing of copy and paste but in a really fast way.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the whole site's posts and/or pages in an XML file through the Tools > Export option of the Wordpress backend and then upload that XML file into the new clean instance of Wordpress using the Tools > Import option. After that you can enable themes and plugins one at the time to see which one is causing trouble.